# How should I set up dielines so that they are not printed?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, print-production, dieline

I want to add that white lines on the project, but don't want that line to be visible on the printed element. How can I do that? Working in CMYK in Adobe CS6.

[image: example]

Comment: I need really basic "how to" for Illustrator. I just start using it.

Comment: Add a layer, using the layers pallette and draw your lines in there. Hide that layer (by clicking on its eye icon in the layers pallette) before actually printing/exporting.

Comment: These are usually referred to as [dielines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dieline "A dieline is used in graphic design as a placeholder for assisting in the proper layout of a document that will be diecut as part of the finishing process."), I've modified your question title to use that term. If this is inaccurate, feel free to roll back the edit

Answer (score 7):

In Illustrator, keep your die lines in a separate layer. You can set that layer to non-print in the Layer Options dialog (double click on the layer).

[image: Illustrator Layer options dialog]

Checking the **Template** box will also make it a non-print layer:

[image: Illustrator Layer options dialog]

When you go to print, make sure that **Visible & Printable Layers** is selected for Print Layers.

[image: Illustrator Print dialog]

Comment: +1: is not really stated explicitly here, but it is a really good idea to label the layer "DIE LINES DO NOT PRINT" (etc) and then tell your printer the file has a layer that says "DIE LINES DO NOT PRINT" and that the DIE LINES DO NOT PRINT. And then if the proofs you receive have the die lines, remind them on the sign-off sheet that the DIE LINES DO NOT PRINT. Sounds crazy and redundant, but it will save someone money and headaches

Comment: @horatio that's a solid bit of advice. I have modified the question title to broaded it a bit, I think your comment would make a great additional answer!

Comment: I think your answer is good and covers what needs to be covered, and it even has the layer labeled well. Because there is a need and a way to print the layer even when flagged (as in your last example image), they just need to communicate clearly with their service provider so that they can catch it if the operator changes the setting or their software preferences override the saved setting.

Answer (score 2):

## Use overprint on stroke

You simply set that line to "Overprint" in the "Attribute" panel of Illustrator. This way that line will not affect any other CMYK or spot separation and will not be "trapped."

[image: Attribute panel Illustrator trapping overprint]

## Also, use a spot color on that stroke and rename it

That white line should also be a "spot color" and you should rename that spot color "dieline"; this way the printer will clearly see you have an extra dieline added to your artwork.

**Double-click on your color swatch to set the color as spot colors and rename it.**

[image: spot color in Illustrator]

---

And yes you can put that dieline on a separate layer that has the "print" unchecked as JohnB mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

The simple way to achieve that, use the white line as a guide instead of stroke. To make the stroke as a guide, just select the stroke & press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd>. At default, guide will be locked in the art-board. To unlock/lock the guide press <kbd>Atl</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>. This process is very useful for offset printing.