# "Keylines" Layer not appearing in PDF

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf

I have an Illustrator document that has a layer called "keylines" showing some folding lines/design details.  It looks like the following:

[image: Screenshot of document with keylines as it appears in Illustrator]

When I save the document as a PDF, however, these lines do not appear, as follows:

[image: Screenshot of document without keylines as it appears in Acrobat]

I cannot determine how to preserve this layer when saving as a PDF.  I have unticked "Create Acrobat Layers from Top-Level Layers" in the Save dialog but this has not helped.

Comment: Do they still not show up when you zoom in?

Comment: @AndrewH They do not, and that is fairly zoomed in (150% in Acrobat Reader DC).

Comment: The lines may be saved in a layer with the "Template" option on. Double-click the layer and see if the "Template" option is selected, this will cause the layer not to print/export.

Here is a related ticket where the user is trying to find a way to make sure the lines won't print. Kind of the opposite of what you're trying to do.

http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28253/how-should-i-set-up-dielines-so-that-they-are-not-printed

Comment: @KoldBane The layer options enabled for this layer are Lock, Show and Preview.  Print is unticked as is Template.  Ticking Print has caused them to appear as desired.  Can you make this an answer so I can give you credit?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines may be saved in a layer with the "Template" option on (or "Print" option off).

Double-click the layer and see if the "Template" option is selected, this will cause the layer not to print/export (or see if the "Print" option is selected, if not, select it).